# Magento 2 is not inserting into "quote_shipping_rate" table?

Tags: magento2, checkout, database, shipping

I have done my homework and I know what the problem is with my website, but I don't know how to solve it

## The Symptoms

When a ***new*** user clicks on place order, he receives an empty error message preventing him from proceeding. see the image below

[image]

The fact that it happens only to new users tells me that this is a recent problem but I don't remember what has changed since.

## The Error

The error that I see in the apache log after this happens is the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCarrier() on boolean in /var/www/public/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php:119
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation(1, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor))
#1 /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)
#2 /var/www/public/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(1, Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor))
#3 /var/www/public/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.ph in /var/www/public/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php on line 119
```

## The Problem

After extensive debugging, I have identified the problem as that Magento 2 is no longer saving new rows to the table `quote_shipping_rate`. That's why existing customers who already have their records saved in this table are able to checkout with no problem. But for new customers (or guests) this problem occurs.

I don't know where Magento 2 is supposed to insert new records in this table even after debugging (I'm using XDebug) and I don't know what causes it to stop inserting the new records.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

The list of all modules and extensions I have can be found here: https://pastebin.com/u1uigaSL

(Magento version is 2.2.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

It turned out that the problem was due to an extension that I was using. Specifically, `Magestore_StorePickup`

After disabling it, the problem went away.

Comment: Hi @Hassan Al-Jeshi. I'm currently experiencing a similar issue (question 284537) but I do not have the same module as you did installed. 

Would you be able to let me know how you found which module was causing the problem or provide any other advice about how to fix the issue? 

Thanks

Comment: @CJNotts I have just disabled the extensions one by one and see what fixed the issue. After each extension I disable, I clear cache and deploy static content

Comment: Thanks I'll get onto that. I've got an idea which one it is now.

Comment: In case the extension was "Shipping Table Rates" by Amasty. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, but i haven't figured out the cause yet.  Mine seems to be intermittent.  However, I do use amasty table rates and ship restrictions.  I've disable amasty table rates to see if it's the culprit or not. But I haven't updated it since last year, and this problem only started recently.