# Customers Cannot checkout as guest in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, quote, guest-checkout

Several of our customers have complained that they cannot checkout as a guest.

The issue seems to have started around the time we upgraded to Magento 2.3.2.

I have tried to checkout as a guest myself and when I click the "Place Order" button I get a blank error message on the page.

[image]

Checking in the developer console I also found the following errors displayed:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   /rest/default/V1/guest-carts/JxzHZPwfSjViq24inacrHuFynyOBAOCC/payment-information:1
>
> jquery.js:10254 POST
>   https://www.mywebsite.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/JxzHZPwfSjViq24inacrHuFynyOBAOCC/payment-information
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I have checked in the Apache logs and found numerous instances of the following error:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call
>   to a member function getCarrier() on boolean in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php:196\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php(154):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->limitShippingCarrier(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Interceptor))\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation('HXVzgs4yJY4TuJT...',
>   'customeremail@gmail.c...',
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor))\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePayme...\n',
>   referer: https://www.mywebsite.com/checkout/

A similar issue has been reported in issue [281311](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281311/magento-2-is-not-inserting-into-quote-shipping-rate-table) however we do not have the module specified in the answer there activated. So I cannot implement the solution provided.

The Modules we currently have on the site are as follows.

```
List of enabled modules:

Magento_Store
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
Magento_Directory
Magento_Amqp
Magento_Config
Magento_Theme
Magento_Backend
Magento_Variable
Magento_Eav
Magento_Search
Magento_Backup
Magento_Customer
Magento_AdminNotification
Magento_Authorization
Magento_BundleImportExport
Magento_CacheInvalidate
Magento_Indexer
Magento_Cms
Magento_Security
Magento_GraphQl
Magento_CatalogImportExport
Magento_Catalog
Magento_CatalogInventory
Magento_Rule
Magento_Msrp
Magento_CatalogRule
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
Magento_StoreGraphQl
Magento_Widget
Magento_Quote
Magento_SalesSequence
Magento_Payment
Magento_CmsGraphQl
Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_User
Magento_Sales
Magento_Checkout
Magento_EavGraphQl
Magento_ConfigurableProduct
Magento_Contact
Magento_Cookie
Magento_Cron
Magento_CurrencySymbol
Magento_Authorizenet
Magento_Integration
Magento_CustomerGraphQl
Magento_CustomerImportExport
Magento_Deploy
Magento_Developer
Magento_Dhl
Magento_AsynchronousOperations
Magento_DirectoryGraphQl
Magento_Downloadable
Magento_CatalogGraphQl
Magento_ImportExport
Magento_Bundle
Magento_BundleGraphQl
Magento_CatalogSearch
Magento_AdvancedSearch
Magento_Email
Magento_EncryptionKey
Magento_Fedex
Magento_GiftMessage
Magento_GoogleAdwords
Magento_GoogleAnalytics
Magento_Ui
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_PageCache
Magento_GroupedProduct
Magento_GroupedImportExport
Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableImportExport
Magento_AuthorizenetAcceptjs
Magento_InstantPurchase
Magento_Analytics
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_Shipping
Magento_LayeredNavigation
Magento_Marketplace
Magento_MediaStorage
Magento_MessageQueue
Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
Magento_Multishipping
Magento_MysqlMq
Magento_NewRelicReporting
Magento_Newsletter
Magento_OfflinePayments
Magento_SalesRule
Magento_GraphQlCache
Magento_Vault
Magento_Paypal
Magento_Captcha
Magento_PaypalCaptcha
Magento_Persistent
Magento_ProductAlert
Magento_ProductVideo
Magento_CheckoutAgreements
Magento_QuoteAnalytics
Magento_QuoteGraphQl
Magento_ReleaseNotification
Magento_Reports
Magento_RequireJs
Magento_Review
Magento_ReviewAnalytics
Magento_Robots
Magento_Rss
Magento_Elasticsearch
MSP_ReCaptcha
Magento_SalesAnalytics
Magento_SalesGraphQl
Magento_SalesInventory
Magento_OfflineShipping
Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable
Magento_UrlRewrite
Magento_Elasticsearch6
Magento_CustomerAnalytics
Magento_SendFriend
Magento_SendFriendGraphQl
Magento_Signifyd
Magento_Sitemap
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl
Magento_Webapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync
Magento_Swatches
Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation
Magento_Tax
Magento_TaxGraphQl
Magento_TaxImportExport
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl
Magento_ThemeGraphQl
Magento_Tinymce3
Magento_Translation
Magento_GoogleOptimizer
Magento_Ups
Magento_SampleData
Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CatalogAnalytics
Magento_Usps
Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
Magento_Braintree
Magento_VaultGraphQl
Magento_Version
Magento_Swagger
Magento_WebapiAsync
Magento_WebapiSecurity
Magento_Weee
Magento_WeeeGraphQl
Magento_CatalogWidget
Magento_Wishlist
Magento_WishlistAnalytics
Magento_WishlistGraphQl
Adyen_Payment
Amasty_Base
Amasty_Conditions
Amasty_CommonRules
Amasty_Pgrid
Amasty_ShippingArea
Amasty_ShippingTableRates
Amasty_Shiprestriction
Amasty_Shiprules
Amazon_Core
Amazon_Login
Amazon_Payment
Dotdigitalgroup_Email
Ess_M2ePro
Foregenix_FgxWeb
Infortis_Infortis
Infortis_Brands
Infortis_Cgen
Infortis_Dataporter
Infortis_Base
Infortis_UltraMegamenu
Infortis_UltraSlideshow
Infortis_Ultimo
Magento_PaypalReCaptcha
MSP_TwoFactorAuth
Magenest_Core
Magenest_SagePay
Mageplaza_Core
Mageplaza_Gdpr
Mirasvit_Core
Mirasvit_Report
Mirasvit_Rewards
Moogento_Core
Moogento_License
Moogento_PickPack
Trade_Tform
Vertex_Tax
Wyomind_Core
Wyomind_OrderEraser
Wyomind_OrdersExportTool
Xtento_XtCore
Xtento_CustomTrackers

List of disabled modules:

Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Klarna_Core
Klarna_Ordermanagement
Klarna_Kp
Temando_Shipping
```

If anyone could shed some light on this problem or provide instructions on how to find out which module (if any) is causing the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you tried  to check after disabling all the third-party modules?

Comment: Hi. I've been disabling them one at a time to try to find if one is causing this error but unfortunately I haven't had any luck as yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have now been resolved.

Thanks to @Hassan Al-Jesh and @Mitro for their advice.

It turns out that it was the extension ["Shipping Table Rates" by Amasty](https://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates-for-magento-2.html) that was causing the issue.

As I needed this extension to calculate shipping, simply disabling it (as in [281311](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281311/magento-2-is-not-inserting-into-quote-shipping-rate-table/282237?noredirect=1#comment407786_282237)) was not an option.

The solution was simply to delete all of the extension files (including the base files) and upload the latest version from the Amasty website.

I believe the issue may have been version compatibility as the version of "Shipping Table Rates" I had been using was fairly old and may not have been compatible with the latest Magento 2.3 version.

In any case the upgrade seems to have resolved the issue.